# Support for Sybase UDFs in Rapid SQL 7.7

Tags: sap-ase

I am new to Sybase and having coded in Oracle server for so many years I wanted to pack some reusable code into a function in Sybase ASE 15.

Based on what I have found, functions or User Defined Functions (UDFs) as they called in the Sybase world is a new feature in Sybase 15 ASE. I use Embarcadero Rapid SQL 7.7 for my coding and it does not even seem to have a node for Functions (as it does for Procedures and other database objects under a database tree).

I am able to create a simple function but it does not show-up anywhere in the left hand side organizer panel of Rapid SQL. Am I missing something basic as I am new to Rapid SQL or the tool - Rapid SQL, in its current version 7.7- is not designed to support functions in Sybase as functions are new to Sybase?

Though Sybase ASE 15 supports functions if it is not visible in the tool I do not want to use it as it makes it harder for maintenance. Is Rapid SQL planning to support UDFs in Sybase in the future?

Is there a work around for using a stored procedure as a function in Sybase ASE 15?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Sybase Central.
With that, check the Functions Folder under the Database and they will be there!

Answer (score 0):

Rapid SQL 8.0 does indeed have support for UDF's.  Visit the enbarcadero site to download the 8.0.2 version of Rapid SQL.  Shoot me an email if you have any issues getting it.  scott.walz@embarcadero.com